# How to do running subtraction in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know how to do running sum but can't figure out how to do running subtract.

Example: we have single column of data and a new column will be formed for running subtraction.

```
Value
------
10
 1
 3
 4
```

Output needs to be:

```
10
 9
 6
 2
```

I need both these columns next to each other

Any suggestion please.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your results depend on the ordering of the rows.  Please be explicit about the column used for ordering.

Comment: Yes for ordering i have a column with integer sequence

Answer (score 3):

Your question only makes sense if you have a column that specifies the ordering.  In that case:

```
select (case when row_number() over (order by <ordercol>) = 1
             then col
             else 2 * first_value(col) over (<ordercol>) - sum(col) over (order by <ordercol>) 
        end) as output
from t;
```

That is, return the column value on the first row.  Otherwise, the math is a little tricky.  But you want the first value minus the sum of the *rest* of the column.  Arithmetically, this is the same as twice the first value minus the cumulative sum.

EDIT:

As Shawn points out, this can be simplified to:

```
select 2 * first_value(col) over (<ordercol>) - sum(col) over (order by <ordercol>) as output
from t;
```

Comment: `2 * first_value(col) over (<ordercol>) - sum(col) over (order by <ordercol>)` works by itself on all rows. Is there a reason to favor catching the first row as a special case?

Comment: @shawnt00 . . . Excellent point.  The reason is that it didn't work for the first iteration of the answer.  Getting the right expression was actually trickier than I expected.